# How to consume functions which are passed as props using spread operator

Tags: reactjs

How to consume individual functions in another component which are passed as a props using spread operator in React.

```
const Component=(props)=>
{
  const A=()=>  
   {  
    }
  const B=()=>
    {
    }
  render(){
         return(
                <Anothercomponent RenderChild={(props)=>{<Component {...props} />}}
                );
          }
 }


const Anothercomponent=()=>
   {
       render(){
       const {RenderChild} = this.props;
       return(

                 //how to consume function A here
              );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Component a React.Component and declare the A function as a static method if you do not use any .this context in it. So to use it just call Component.A() [learn more](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't passed function `A` and `B` as props

Second, you are making use of functional components and hence you would get access to props from the function arguments and not `this.props`. Also it need to use render method. If you make use of render, you need to define your components as class components

```
const Anothercomponent=(props)=> {
    const { RenderChild } = props;
    return(
        <div>Another component</div>
    );
}

const Component=(props)=> {
   const A=()=> {}
   const B=()=> {}
   return(
        <Anothercomponent RenderChild={(props)=>{<Component {...props} />}}
  );
}
```